# Calculating the average percentage of a bunch of figures in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, excel-formula

Basically, I'm trying to calculate the total average outage hours of a worksheet I'm working with, however I'm trying to have it further broken down.

Here is a picture of the Excel Sheet:

**Excel Calculations**

[image]

(Not allowed to add embedded pictures yet :( - 10 reputation needed, sorry!)

Pretty much, I'm trying to calculate what the average up-time is for the month, by calculating the average downtime and then subtracting it from 100.00%

What I've got works, but I'm trying to workout whether the Outage Hours column can be scrapped, and the total can be calculated with perhaps just a larger formula.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet: https://www.dropbox.com/s/msowjndootd2hh2/Spreadsheet%20Calculations.xlsx?dl=0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, you're looking for the result from the second column without having to include the second column, correct?

Since the second column is just the remaining difference (from 1.00) of the first column, then to get the result, all you have to do is take the remaining difference for the **maximum overall** to the **total sum** of the first column.

Meaning (assuming 12 months)...:

`=12-SUM(B4:B15)`

(Substitute `12` for however many months to be summed)

EDIT: OP is looking for `=AVERAGE(B4:B15)`

Comment: Hi Den, thanks for answering! - So what I'm looking for is the B16 value, however without the C column (if this is possible - correct me if this is not possible). I tried using that all the figures for the month b4:b15 (which is the figure I need) but it came out as something weird like 910.42

Comment: Also to clarify - B4:B15 are the figures for the month, I have another worksheet which changes the month with a drop down box - these are the figures for a bunch of different services (part of my project)

Comment: @G. Dimitriou umm... I'm not sure I'm understanding.  The final number in the B column, B16, the 75.87%, is just the average of the above numbers, correct?  `=AVERAGE(B4:B15)`  This is all you're looking for?

Comment: I feel so silly right now.... I guess it is just using the =AVERAGE formula, thanks a heap anyway! (I'd upvote, but I don't have enough rep yet) - as for me, I think I need some more sleep lol!

Comment: @G.Dimitriou as the OP you should click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in and accept it.  Other members in the community should Upvote his answer if they feel like it satisfies the question.  Which I do +1

Comment: @Thomas Inzina Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasInzina Thanks for that tip, and done :) Btw what does OP stand for? - I'm assuming it relates to me being the one who asked the question.

Comment: Original Poster(OP).  Welcome to StackOverflow(SO).:)

Comment: @ThomasInzina Thanks for that! And Thank you, SO definitely has been really useful so far :)